# What this thing is and what it's used for?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, history

Images:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I'm not sure if this is the right stackexchange to ask this question but i haven't found a "gas display detection and measuring devices" stackexchange so physics seems like a somewhat reasonable place to ask.

I've found something looking like a chandelier i'm supposed to sell online on my job and i have no idea what it is used for, all i can gather is that there are three compasses that function and that can be locked in place with a small lever. the outside of the wooden box says:

"Hermann Sewerin

Vorm. Vulkan-Werk GMBH

Gaspatex(R)

Gütersloh i. Wf.

Gas-Anzeige-Spür- und Messgeräte"

Meaning gas display detection and measuring devices from a german manufacturer of such devices.

Thanks for any help, or for pointing me in the right direction to ask.

Comment: Are the three gauges indeed compassses? They do not appear to be pointing in the same direction. Are there any units on the gauges?

Comment: certainly this is not the site. You should ask someplace as https://www.ha.com/free-appraisals.s , where they might  already know what this was used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that thing indicates the magnetic field strength emanating from a tube carrying a current of electricity through the hole in the center of the device. it is an antique and hasn't been used for this purpose for probably 75 years.